# Ask Ubuntu Newsletter signs me up for Astronomy Newsletter?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I saw a community ad for the newsletter pop-up and subscribed

[image]

However, this is what I received in my inbox with regards to confirmation:

[image]

I do <3 Astronomy and all but I currently don't even have an account there! Could this please be resolved to avoid further confusion?

Comment: It would be hilarious if Astronomy people got Ubuntu questions, heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ack, sorry about that. As you discovered, there's a newsletters bug in which sites get mixed up. I've turned off newsletters (globally) for now, and will gradually roll them out again later tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Will I see the ad once again? Or is there a more direct method for me to sign up for the newsletter?

Comment: Once the newsletter feature is turned on for askubuntu.com (early next week), you'll be able to sign up via the ad or on your user edit page. Newsletters are enabled for all "sketchy"-themed beta sites as of now, so you can check it out on a site like http://skeptics.stackexchange.com.